# How can I prevent JavaScript functions from autorunning?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have defined a function as follows in a knockout Model.  When a user clicks on an edit address button on the list, this will show the address form and fill it with the selected address.

```
        this.editAddress = function (address) {
            self.addressErrors([]);
            self.showAddressForm(1);
            self.formAddress(address);
        }
```

However, this function runs immediately when defined and the form is shown on pageload. What can I do to prevent this?

here is the list html with bindings (simplified)

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: userAddresses">
    <li>
        <div>
            <p data-bind="text: addressTitle"></p>
            <p data-bind="text: nameSurname"></p>
            <p>
                <span data-bind="text: addressLine1"></span> <span data-bind="text: addressLine2"></span>
            </p>
            <p><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.editAddress($data)">Edit address</button></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show the HTML button that binds to the function and the model's definition.

Comment: When you define a function, like you have above, it will not run. You must call the function first. To troubleshoot this, i advise placing a console.log("Made it here") line into your function to see if its running. If you have multiple similar functions, i advise to place a unique console log.

Comment: well i guess this question is more about the knockout click binding. somehow it runs the defined function on bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's executing immediately, I think your form binding is executing it.

In particular, this line:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.editAddress($data)">Edit address</button></p>
```

Note your click binding is `$root.editAddress($data)`

Change your binding to be the following:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.editAddress">Edit address</button></p>
```

Note the removal of `($data)`.  `click:` expects a function reference.

Removing `($data)` will stop the binding from executing your function immediately.  (Before you were causing `$root.editAddress` to be called immediately, and it would return 'undefined', so your `click:` was effectively bound to `undefined`.)

Note that knockout passes `$data` to your function automatically, so you don't need to do anything tricky.

Comment: Just figured that out and you saved me from answering my own question.  And that is a nice explanation to the issue. :)

Comment: @Azadrum Seems to be the answer always comes moments after asking... :-)  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have the action occur on an event, such as a click. I'm not familiar with knockout.js but, this might be helpful.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the documentation. Re-read it and got that if i use the binding like data-bind="click: $root.editAddress($data) it will autorun the editAddress.